# WildFly/JPA database connection leak in multitenant software

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I want to use a multitenant architecture for our Java EE software.
We use WildFly 8.2 (JPA with Hibernate 4.3.7) with PostgreSQL 9.3

I know Hibernate provide some API for multitenant : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

and that we can integrate it with JPA in the persistence.xml file like this :

```
<property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA"/>
<property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="mycompany.hibernate.multitenant.SchemaResolver"/>
<property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="mycompany.hibernate.multitenant.MultiTenantProvider"/>
```

But i have some problems with my "hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider".

I want to use the datasource pool from my WildFly configuration (standalone.xml), but if i use it, it result in connection leak in pool.
The connections are never released to the pool.

Do i need to use another library to manage my database connection pool like C3P0 ? I though that WildFly can manage it correctly.
Is there a better way to integrate multitenant with JPA ?

Or maybe a problem with my JNDI lookup ?

And if i use SCHEMA for the multitenant configuration, the connection is always to the same database/datasource so why we need to write some connection provider ?

Do you have any ideas ?
Thank in advance for your help.

```
public class MultiTenantProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

@Override
public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class clazz) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> clazz) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
    Context initContext;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        initContext = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:/MyPostgresDS");
        connection = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}

@Override
public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
    final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
    try {
        connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA '" + tenantIdentifier + "'");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
    }
    return connection;
}

@Override
public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    try {
        connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA 'public'");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [public]", e);
    }
    connection.close();
}

@Override
public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    releaseAnyConnection(connection);
}
```

}

Datasource in the standalone.xml file of WildFly

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/MyPostgresDS" pool-name="MyPostgresDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql:demo</connection-url>
                <driver>posgresqlDriver</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                    <password>postgres</password>
                </security>
                <timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>20000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
            </datasource>
```

Comment: nobody can help me about this ? :(

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
    return true; // changing this true from false will fix the leak.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect solution to this problem. You need to try couple of things. Wildfly can't release the idle connection properly if it has been kept open.

Steps to resolve

1. Find query which is keeping connection open: Since you are using postgres use this query to find which query is keeping connection open. If you find the query half job is done.

> SELECT datname, pid, usename, waiting, state, (now()-query_start) AS
>   since, (now() - state_change) AS since2, (now() - backend_start) as
>   since3, (now() - xact_start) as since4, query FROM pg_stat_activity
>   ORDER BY since;

2. Configure wildfly to release connection: Enable idle-time-out

```html
<timeout><idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes></timeout>
```

Also define the flush strategy

```html
<flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
```

To log wildfly connections: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/tomcat-wildfly-configuring-database-connectivity.html

And if you can wildfly 9 you can find leak using http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/wildfly9/detecting-connection-leaks-in-wildfly-9